# retrieve the saved state for a collection of checkboxes from local storage after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, storage, local

i've got a collection of 20 checkboxes like this here:

```
<div class="cbcell">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="home_swimming_pool" name="Basen" value="35"> Basen 
</div>
<div class="cbcell">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="home_sauna" name="Sauna" value="45"> Sauna 
</div>
```

with the following code i am saving and removing the checkbox state in the local storage which works very fine, also the filter function of dataTables works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();

          if($(this).is(':checked')){

          console.log( name, value ); // <- debug  
          oTable.fnFilter(name, value,false,true,false,true);
             localStorage.setItem(this.name,'checked');

          } else {
          console.log( name, value ); // <- debug 
             oTable.fnFilter('',value,false,true,false,true);
             localStorage.removeItem(this.name);
          }
        //})
        });
</script>
```

Please tell me how to retrieve the state of each checkbox after a page reload. I tried it already with several functions and my last stand is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                      if (localStorage.getItem(this.value) == 'checked'){
                          $(this).attr("checked",true)
                      }

                    })
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In your `document.ready`, what is `this`?

Comment: you've shown what you tried, but haven't said what it does or in what way it's not working for you. How do you know your code for saving and removing works? What is the value of `this.name` and why does it only appear in the localStorage calls while you use `name` (AKA `$(this).attr('name')`) elsewhere? Later, what is the value of `this.value`?

Comment: lovely name btw, Barry White :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked',localStorage.getItem(this.name) == 'checked');
});
```

In **$(document).ready()** function, `this` refers to the document, not to a checkbox, like in the **$(':checkbox').click()**. Plus if you think about it, you really need a way to iterate through your checkboxes. This is where **.each()** comes in. Inside the **$(':checkbox').each()** function, `this` will refer to a specific checkbox

Also it would be a good idea to check that localStorage is actually supported by the browser the code is running on, otherwise you will be getting errors.

a simple way is to wrap everything in an `if (window.localStorage) { /* code here */}`

---

**Improved version**

```
if (window.localStorage) {
    $('.cbcell').on('click',':checkbox',function(){
        var name = this.name;
        var value = this.value;

          if($(this).is(':checked')){
             oTable.fnFilter(name, value,false,true,false,true);
             //shorthand to check that localStorage exists
             localStorage && localStorage.setItem(this.name,'checked');

          } else {
             oTable.fnFilter('',value,false,true,false,true);
             //shorthand to check that localStorage exists
             localStorage && localStorage.removeItem(this.name);
          }
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('checked',localStorage.getItem(this.name) == 'checked');
        });
    });
}
```

---

Finally may I suggest spending some time going through the **excellent** [Try jQuery](http://try.jquery.com/) tutorial at http://try.jquery.com/